# Custom UIView which handles touches, above UIWebview does not pass on touches to UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uitouch

Tried all of the following, I would expect the touches to be passed on, but they are not:

(a)UIWebView has user interactions enabled (always).
(b) Custom UIView has multiple touches enabled, and exclusiveTouch = NO (default)
(c) I tried calling

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]
```

and also called 'super' in the other 3 touch handling methods in the custom UIView.
But still the touches are not passed on to the UIWebView (ie, tapping on links on the UIWebView etc. does not work)

(d) Also, created a reference to the web view in the UIView class and instead of calling super call that reference for 'touchesBegan:' and the rest. This also does not seem to work.

Note: The custom UIView subclass and the web view are subviews of a container UIView.

Is something missing here? Any other way (with gesture recognizers or something, to pass on the touches?)

LAYOUT

-Container UIView:

---Custom UIView (in front)

---UIWebView (behind)

Comment: super of you custom UIView is not the UIWebView (unless your custom view inherits UIWebView) so all messages to super will be passed to UIView and are irrelevant for your cause. How do you layout your views ?

Comment: In this setup you are passing the touches to the UIView that contains the UIWebView not the UIWebView itself. Create a reference to the web view in the UIView class and instead of calling super call that reference.

Comment: Yes, super of my custom UIView is another UIView, it is not a UIWebView